# Display tax class in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to display the tax name that applies to a product on the product page (the same tax class that is configured on the product).

This is what I wan to show:

Price: 100 U$S + Sample Tax

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This returns the Name of the Tax-Class:

```
$taxClassId = $_product->getTaxClassId();
$taxClass = Mage::getModel('tax/class')->load($taxClassId);
$taxClassName = $taxClass->getClassName();
```